# Jest: Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...), but I'm not updating it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a super simple test doing this:

```
  it('renders', () => {
    const { toJSON } = render(
      <MockedProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </MockedProvider>
    )

    expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

that's literally it. I have some `reactiveVar` logic in here and it does a bit of stuff but jest is throwing a ton of errors most notable:

```
Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

I know this is an easy fix if you are updating stuff as you just wrap in act, but why am I seeing this error when I'm just rendering a snapshot? the test is passing but I want to remove all this stuff it's spewing out

Answer (score 0):

Anything that might take time - rendering, user events, **data fetching** - must be completed before any test assertion (before you call `expect()`)

Probably `<MyComponent />` is still resolving some async code (maybe `useEffect(fn)`?) before the assertion.

You'd need to use [`waitFor()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) for solving this:

```
-  it('renders', () => {
+  it('renders', async () => {
    const { toJSON } = render(
      <MockedProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </MockedProvider>
    )

-    expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
+    await waitFor(() => {
+      expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
+    })
  })
```